# Setting same color to NavBar and View but getting different colors on run time

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting the same color on my view background and on my navigation bar. But when I run the code, the colors are different. Don't know what is happening. Someone can help me? :|

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Utils.Color.bgColor
view.backgroundColor = Utils.Color.bgColor

// some trys to fix the problem...
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = Utils.Color.bgColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I use, note the base color is different and I prefer white/yellow text:

**In AppDelegate:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x112A0F)  //my green
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.yellow
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    return true
}
```

**Someplace accessable (for me it's a framework because I use this elsewhere:**

```
public func UIColorFromRGB(_ rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Yes, you may use `UIColorFromRGB` in `AppDelegate`. The largest difference I see is you include `'isOpaque`. Try removing that first.